# Как сделать многоуровневое меню в Telegram боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть такая клава ( под чатом появляется). Нужно сделать что бы при клике на кнопку. эти кнопки убирались и поялвлялись другие( в зависимости на какую нажали). как это сделать ?

[image: Вот такая]

вот её код.

```
from telebot import types

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(m):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['О нас', 'Прайс-лист']])
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Акции', 'Контакты']])
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, '123',
        reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Тоже интересует такое меню!! если решение есть поделись кодом пожалуйста!!!

Comment: Тоже интересует такое меню!! если решение есть поделись кодом, буду признателен

Answer (score 1):

А в чем проблема? Просто добавьте обработчик на определенный текст:

```
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def message(message):
    if message.text == 'О нас':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тут инфа о компании'
    elif message.text == 'Прайс-лист':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тут прайс'
```

и т.д. Если нужна клавиатура, то создаешь перед отправкой, но я выношу клавиатуры в отдельный файл.

Comment: +- так же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1108195/234134