# Многоуровневое меню в TelegramBotApi

Tags: telegram-bot, python-3.6, telebot

Я новичок в python, и для практики решил написать игрового телеграмм бота на библиотеке TelegramBotApi, я написал вот такой код меню(не судите строго, я новичок) ),и хотел бы сделать многоуровневое меню(обязательно обычные меню, у которого кнопки на месте клавиатуры , а не инлайновое меню). Например: Я выбираю пункт "Транспорт", и на месте старого меню появляются другие кнопки, например 2 кнопки: 1)Купить еще транспорт,2) Мои виды транспорта (и была кнопка назад), помогите это реализовать. Заранее спасибо!!!

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton("������ Транспорт")
item2 = types.KeyboardButton("������ Оффис")
item3 = types.KeyboardButton("������ Банк")
item4 = types.KeyboardButton("������ Баланс")
item5 = types.KeyboardButton("������ Мини-Игры")
item6 = types.KeyboardButton("������ Рефералы")
item7 = types.KeyboardButton("������ Бонус")
item8 = types.KeyboardButton("������ Донат")
item9 = types.KeyboardButton("������ Наша группа")

markup.row(item1, item2)
markup.row(item3, item4)
markup.row(item5, item6)
markup.row(item7, item8,item9)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''Добро пожаловать, <b>{0.first_name}</b>!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, ������ бот созданный для веселого время провождения.
Введи <b>/help</b>, что бы получить информацию об игре ☝️'''.format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), 
parse_mode="html",reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_type=['text'])
def lalala(message):
if message.chat.type=="private":
if message.text=="������ Транспорт":
#Что дальше писать?
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я всё верно понял:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def cmd_start(message):
    start = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)

    start.row('Wunderlist')
    start.row('Telegraph')
    start.row('Погода')
    start.row('Контакты')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери сервис', reply_markup=start)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    service = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    service.row('Wunderlist')
    service.row('Telegraph')
    service.row('Погода')
    wunderlist = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    wunderlist.row('/create')
    wunderlist.row('/task')
    wunderlist.row('/delete')
    wunderlist.row('Сервисы')
    telegraph = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    telegraph.row('/create')
    telegraph.row('/page')
    telegraph.row('Сервисы')
    weather = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    weather.row('/location')
    weather.row('/city')
    weather.row('Сервисы')
    if message.text == "Wunderlist":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что будем делать?', reply_markup=wunderlist)
    if message.text == "Telegraph":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напишем что-нибудь?', reply_markup=telegraph)
    if message.text == "Погода":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери способ получение прогноза', reply_markup=weather)
    if message.text == "Сервисы":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери сервис', reply_markup=service)
```